# How to get partial information from JSON data in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, regex, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a list of JSON data and hope to extract all ids from "data-target-user-id". How can I do this using regex or beautifulsoup?

```
my_lst_JSON = [‘<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="115389" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>’,
               ‘<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="1109" user-type="9" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>’,
               ‘<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="2890" user-type="7" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>’,
               ‘<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="22567" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>’,
               ‘<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="33872" user-type="1" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>’]
```

Expected outputs:

```
['115389', '1109', '2890', '22567', '33872']
```

I tried the approach suggested by @zx485 with the coding below:

ids_lst = []

```
for data in my_lst_JSON:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
    ids_lst.append([item.text for item in soup.findAll('div/@user-id')])
```

It returns a blank list...

Any thought is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: This is XML wrapped in JSON. Unwrap the XML and extract the relevant parts with XPath `div/@user-id`.

Comment: No...This is only a part of the string and it's a sample list. @MendelG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
        
my_lst_JSON = ['<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="115389" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
         '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="1109" user-type="9" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
         '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="2890" user-type="7" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
         '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="22567" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
         '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="33872" user-type="1" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>']
        
user_ids = [bs(item).find("div")["user-id"] for item in my_lst_JSON]
print(user_ids)
```

But I like @Boomshakalaka solution better, it's more elegant

```
import re
my_lst_JSON = ['<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="115389" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
 '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="1109" user-type="9" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
 '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="2890" user-type="7" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
 '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="22567" user-type="8" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>',
 '<div id="a-exse-tile" class="j-exse profile-tile" data-exp-enabled="true" user-id="33872" user-type="1" data-viewing-self="false" <!--section --></div></div></div>']

user_ids = [re.findall('\d+|$', item)[0] for item in my_lst_JSON]
print(user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall('\d+|$', my_lst_JSON[0])[0]` is working!